# Group By Not Grouping as Expected on a field extracted from string

Tags: sql, group-by

I can't get the Group By to behave properly, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

The ItemPath is my issue, I believe. When I use Group By, it's grouping by the ItemPath, which can vary in length and content even though the ReportName at the end of the path is the same. I need them grouped by ReportName, not the actual ItemPath. I'm not sure what I'm missing to get that to happen. You can see my code results below. They should be grouped by the name, but they aren't because the ItemPath can be different so only some of them match up.

I tried creating a derived table and grouping by the ReportName column, but that produced the same result since I had to include the ItemPath in the group by clause due to it not being aggregated in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT Count(ItemPath) AS ExecutionCount, 
        RIGHT(ItemPath, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([ItemPath]), 0) - 1) AS ReportName, 
        SUM([TimeDataRetrieval]) AS TimeDataRetrievalSum, 
        SUM([TimeProcessing]) AS TimeProcessingSum, 
        SUM([ByteCount]) AS ByteCountSum, 
        SUM([RowCount]) AS RowCountSum
 FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog3]
 WHERE ItemPath LIKE '%/example/%' AND 
       ItemPath NOT LIKE '%placeholder%' AND 
       ItemPath NOT LIKE '%example2%'
GROUP BY ItemPath
ORDER BY ExecutionCount DESC
```

Current results sample ("Invoice" should be grouped, but they aren't):

```
| ExecutionCount | ReportName |TimeDataRetrievalSum|
| -------------- | ---------- |--------------------|
| 1246           | Invoice    |82303               |
| 41             | Invoice    |6303                |
| 8              |Remittance  |153                 |
```

Thanks!

Comment: just group by  : RIGHT(ItemPath, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([ItemPath]), 0) - 1)

Comment: You have two reports with ```Invoice``` names in distinct paths

Comment: @Adamszsz Wow, I knew it would be something straightforward I wasn't thinking of. Thank you! That worked.

Comment: Good to hear that :) , please vote answear on question if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this :

```
SELECT Count(ItemPath) AS ExecutionCount, 
        RIGHT(ItemPath, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([ItemPath]), 0) - 1) AS ReportName, 
        SUM([TimeDataRetrieval]) AS TimeDataRetrievalSum, 
        SUM([TimeProcessing]) AS TimeProcessingSum, 
        SUM([ByteCount]) AS ByteCountSum, 
        SUM([RowCount]) AS RowCountSum
 FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog3]
 WHERE ItemPath LIKE '%/example/%' AND 
       ItemPath NOT LIKE '%placeholder%' AND 
       ItemPath NOT LIKE '%example2%'
GROUP BY RIGHT(ItemPath, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([ItemPath])
ORDER BY ExecutionCount DESC
```